# How to overwrite a specific chunk in a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, audio-recording, overwrite

Given a **bytearray** and a new **bytearray** of which i need to overwrite its content on the original `bytearray` but **starting** from a specific **position/offset** (A) as shown in the image below(we can say B is the **length** of the new Array).
Also handling the new **length** if the overwriting **exceeds** the actual length of the original array.

(this is needed for **.WAV** file overwriting in different positions).

[image]
[image]

here is what i have tried so far but no luck.

```
 public byte[] ByteArrayAppender(byte[] firstData, byte[] newData, byte[] remainData, int Position) {

    byte[] editedByteArray = new byte[firstData.length + newData.length + remainData.length];


    System.arraycopy(firstData, 0, editedByteArray, 0, Position);

    System.arraycopy(newData, 0, editedByteArray, firstData.length, newData.length);

    System.arraycopy(remainData, 0, editedByteArray, newData.length, remainData.length);

    return editedByteArray;

}
```

Comment: I can hardly imagine an answer to this question that is easier than the `System#arraycopy` method. But maybe 'fge' got it right...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `ByteBuffer` to wrap your original array:

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(theOriginalArray);
buf.position(whereYouWant);
buf.put(theNewArray);
```

Note: above code does not check for overflows etc. If an overflow is possible, the code will have to change for something like this and the method should return the array:

```
final int targetLength = theNewArray.length + offset;
final boolean overflow = targetLength > theOriginalArray.length;
final ByteBuffer buf;

if (overflow) {
    buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(targetLength);
    buf.put(theOriginalArray);
    buf.rewind();
} else
    buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(theOriginalArray);

buf.position(offset);
buf.put(theNewArray);

return buf.array(); // IMPORTANT
```

Comment: and the buf.array(); will give me the new overwritten array ?

Comment: This code just modifies the original array -- and in this case, yes, using `.array()` will return your original array, not a new one. From your question, this is what you want, isn't it? Or do you want a _new_ array to be created?

Comment: it works, I've used this with WAV audio data, overwriting with the old data with newly recorded one, when i overwrite the beginning and the end it works fine, but in the middle i get trouble, only noise.

Comment: Note that you need to create a new `ByteBuffer` for each overwrite operation; if you don't want to do so, you'll need to `.rewind()` it before each overwrite you want to make. It is lightweight enough that you can afford creating a new one each time though.

Comment: when the new data exceeds the lenght of the original data i get java.nio.BufferOverflowException.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the post ;) "Note: above code does not check for overflows etc.". In this case you'll need to create a _new_ array, see `ByteBuffer.allocate()`. Calculating its length is left as an exercise ;)

Comment: when do i allocate before wrapping or after ?

Comment: Then you'll need to ask a question with some more code in it. Given the code extracts you provide, it is difficult to see what the problem can be...

Comment: i'm using your code, the same exact method that overwrites the original byte array with a new one, no need for posting code, the exception when we exceed the size of the original byte array i get the java.nio.BufferOverflowException that's it.

Comment: Sorry but I seriously doubt it. More code extracts will probably tell more. I have tested that code and it Works For Me(tm).

Comment: your code is working my bad, i was giving an erroneous position :)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to override byteArray as follow..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] array1 = new byte[10];
    byte[] array2 = new byte[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array1[i] = (byte) 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        array2[i] = (byte) 0;
    }
    Test.overrideArray(3, array1, array2);
}

private static void overrideArray(int start, byte[] originalArray, byte[] overrideArray) {
    //add some codes for check validations lengths of Arrays
    for (int i = start; i - start < overrideArray.length; i++) {
        originalArray[i] = overrideArray[i - start];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(originalArray[i]);
    }
}
```