# Replace String in byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

Welcome,
I have a `byte[]` which is the binary representation of a `String`. And I wanted to replace a part of this `String` and get back the new `byte[]`!
I have tried:

```
String string = new String(array);
string = string.replace("#+#","SOME STRING");
array = string.getBytes();
```

The problem is that array is that the array afterwards is something different and not only because of the replacement.

The content of the array are serialized objects seperated with "#+#".

Comment: what are the array values before and after replace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906002/how-to-overwrite-a-specific-chunk-in-a-byte-array

Comment: What's the encoding of the serialized file?

Comment: ok ok the serialized file is created as normal ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: I dont know how it is encoded:
`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(target.getPathAsString());
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(T);
  oos.close();
  fos.close();`

Comment: the array is so big that i can not post it here @nafas

Comment: @Murat K. he does not replaces a STRING in this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be explicit about the character encoding you are using and use an encoding such as "Latin-1" where all byte sequences map to valid Unicode characters:

```
String string = new String(array, "Latin-1");
string = string.replace("#+#","SOME STRING");
array = string.getBytes("Latin-1");
```